# alert method runs several times how to fix

Tags: javascript

consider this method inside a class the return value of this method is used to calculate a value in `compute()` so the compute method shouldn't run if return value of `BS()` "BM" is `NaN`
so I added `if(this.BS()== null) return`, however when I don't enter a weight value the alert method runs twice one time for BS() and another time for compute()

```
BS() {
        this.weight = document.getElementById('first').value
        this.height = document.getElementById('second').value
        if (this.weight == '') return alert('please enter weight')
        
        let w = parseFloat(this.weight)
        let h = parseFloat(this.height)
        let BM
        
            BM = w*h
         return BM
  compute(){
if(this.BS()== null) return
  let val= this.BS()/10
  return val
}
```

I tried to use `if(this.BS()== undefined) return` but it also didn't work still the alert runs twice so how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you call `this.BS()` multiple times?

Comment: (1) `this.BS() == null` will be `false` for `BM === NaN`. `x == null` is only `true` for `null` and `undefined`. (2) Call `this.BS()` once and store the result in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseFloat` will return either a number or `NaN`, never `null` -- therefore your early return won't work. Replacing `if (this.BS()== null)` with `if (Number.isNaN(this.BS()))` should give you the expected behaviour.

Another interesting way of doing the same check would be this:

```
        const bsValue = this.BS();
        if(bsValue !== bsValue) return
```

That works because `NaN` is the only number which is not equal to itself.

Comment: But i don't have a variable called Number, so when i write if(Number.IsNAN(this.BS())) return. i won't get an error ?

Comment: `Number` is part of JavaScript — it will be available for you

Comment: isNAN()/Number.isNAN didn't work can't understand why ?

Comment: Did you write `Number.isNaN` though? Case matters here, `Number.isNaN` exists but `Number.isNAN` is undefined

Comment: I took it copy past didn't work at all have u tried it urself and worked with u ?

Answer (score 0):

you are calling Bs method twice inside compute method. thats why you are seeing this error. if you are using BS() only inside compute then you can use this

```
       BS() {
                this.weight = document.getElementById('first').value
                this.height = document.getElementById('second').value
                if (this.weight == '') return alert('please enter weight')
                
                let w = parseFloat(this.weight)
                let h = parseFloat(this.height)
                 return w*h
       
    compute(){
        const bsValue = this.BS();
        if(bsValue== null) return 

        let val= bsValue/10
        return val
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately i am using this condition in another method not only one so the alert keeps repeating itself so hoew to fix ? isNAN()/Number.isNAN didn't work either

Comment: the problem is you are showing alert in main method(which you are using multiple times). you might have to change your logic. e.g show alert only when user submit and save the values (make separate method) and for calculate make another method with no alert and use saved values.

Comment: i hooked the Bm to the constructor and played with it as i wanted. And yes there was a huge bug in my code i corrected it and now alert is working exactely as expected